# PyOpenGL fragment shader texture sampling

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, textures, pyopengl

All right, thankfully you guys I have a little deeper understanding how *OpenGL* in (almost) the modern work. But there is something I can't figure out.

How can the fragment shader sampling my texture even if I missing it set up correctly? I think somehow the sampler automatically get the texture. But how?

After I commented out the *glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1)* the texture still showed up.

*(I'm using GLSL 1.2 because of my Raspberry Pi.)

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 120

attribute vec2 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTexcoords;

varying vec2 fTexcoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition.x/1.33, vPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    fTexcoords = vTexcoords;
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 120

varying vec2 fTexcoords;
uniform sampler2D textureObj;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureObj, fTexcoords);
}
```

**Code:**

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import numpy, time, sys

def getFileContent(file):
    content = open(file, 'r').read()
    return content

def init():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), HWSURFACE | OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480)

    img = pygame.image.load("brick.jpg")
    textureData = pygame.image.tostring(img, "RGB", 1)
    width = img.get_width()
    height = img.get_height()
    #glGenTextures(1)
    #glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

    vertices = [-0.5, -0.5,
                -0.5, 0.5,
                0.5, 0.5,
                0.5, -0.5]

    texcoords = [0.0, 0.0,
                 0.0, 1.0,
                 1.0, 1.0,
                 1.0, 0.0]

    vertices = numpy.array(vertices, dtype=numpy.float32)
    texcoords = numpy.array(texcoords, dtype=numpy.float32)

    vertexShader = compileShader(getFileContent("helloTriangle.vert"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragmentShader = compileShader(getFileContent("helloTriangle.frag"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    global shaderProgram
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader)
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader)
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram)

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices)
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, texcoords)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

    global texLocation
    texLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "textureObj")

def main():
    init()

    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        glClearColor(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram)
        #glUniform1i(texLocation, 0)
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)

        pygame.display.flip()

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In glsl uniform variables are default initialized by 0 respectively 0.0. So the value of the texture sampler uniform `textureObj` is initialized by (texture unit) 0, too.

Further there is the default texture object (0). If you don't create and bind a named texture object, then there is still the default texture object (0), and [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) specifies the texture image of the default texture object (0).

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 8.1 Texture Objects; page 179](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf)

> Textures in GL are represented by named objects. The name space for texture objects is the unsigned integers, **with zero reserved by the GL to represent the default texture object**. **The default texture object is bound to each of the** `TEXTURE_1D`, **`TEXTURE_2D`**, `TEXTURE_3D`, [...] targets during context initialization.

[GLSL - The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6; 4.3.5. Uniform Variables; page 50](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

> The uniform qualifier is used to declare global variables whose values are the same across the entire primitive being processed. **All uniform variables are read-only and are initialized externally either at link time or through the API**. **The link-time initial value is either the value of the variable’s initializer, if present, or 0 if no initializer is present**.

---

By the way, `glGenTextures` returns a named texture object, which can be bound by `glBindTexture`. It is not specified that the 1st named texture object, which is generated by `glGenTextures`, has to be 1. It can be any id (number).

So it has to be:

```
texID = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID)
```

instead of

<s>`glGenTextures(1)`</s>
<s>`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1)`</s>